# Details of the calculation when referencing a quantized TFLite CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, embedded, tflite

for the purpose of research and learning, I am trying to understand the series of mathematical operations needed to operate when using a CNN quantized model. I started with quantized conv2D layers.

I studied a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05877.pdf) about the quantization method and inference method. As I understand, when operating conv2D, an affine function is applied to input data and kernels; then, we add bias to the result. Finally, we quantize the result to uint8 (also using an affine function), so the uint8 quantized result can be used for the next layer.

I created a very simple model that contains only one conv2D layer, with 1 input channel and 1 output channel. So, the only operation this layer performs is the convolution between the input and the simple kernel that I created.

```
input = np.array([[[[1] for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]])
custom_matrix = np.array([[1,1,1], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [1, 1, 1]]).astype(np.float32)

custom_initializer = Constant(value=custom_matrix)
def creat_model():
    model = Sequential(
        [
             Conv2D(1, (3,3), padding="same", input_shape = (4,4,1),      kernel_initializer=custom_initializer),
           
        ]
    )
    return model

model = creat_model()
```

Then, i quantized the simple model

```
random_matrices = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(50, 4, 4, 1))
print(random_matrices[0].shape)
x_train = random_matrices / 255.0
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
def representative_data_gen():
  for input_value in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train).batch(1).take(40):
    yield [input_value]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8  
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

I succesfully infer using this quantized model (the result of the origin model & of quantized model are quite the same).
But when i print details about the quantized model using

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_quant_model, experimental_preserve_all_tensors=True)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
tensor_details = interpreter.get_tensor_details()

for tensor_detail in tensor_details:
    print(tensor_detail['index'], "   Name: ", tensor_detail["name"])
    print("     Quant_parameters:", tensor_detail["quantization"])
    print("     Type:", tensor_detail["dtype"])
```

The result is

```
0    Name:  serving_default_conv2d_4_input:0
     Quant_parameters: (0.003921568859368563, 0)
     Type: <class 'numpy.uint8'>
1    Name:  sequential_4/conv2d_4/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp
     Quant_parameters: (3.0878494726493955e-05, 0)
     Type: <class 'numpy.int32'>
2    Name:  sequential_4/conv2d_4/Conv2D
     Quant_parameters: (0.007874015718698502, 0)
     Type: <class 'numpy.int8'>
3    Name:  tfl.quantize
     Quant_parameters: (0.003921568859368563, -128)
     Type: <class 'numpy.int8'>
4    Name:  StatefulPartitionedCall:01
     Quant_parameters: (0.023214150220155716, -128)
     Type: <class 'numpy.int8'>
5    Name:  StatefulPartitionedCall:0
     Quant_parameters: (0.023214150220155716, 0)
     Type: <class 'numpy.uint8'>
6    Name:  
     Quant_parameters: (0.0, 0)
     Type: <class 'numpy.int8'>
```

I tried to find documetation about these tensors for many days but i can't. I think that the first tensor is used to convert input value range from [0,1] to [0,255]. The second tensor for operating with bias parameters. The third tensor for convolution operation. But i don know how last tensors operate with their quantization parameters to get final result.

My questions is:

1. How my data calculate thought these tensors with specific input value. And why is the last tensor look so strange (no name and all paramers are equal 0)
2. I tried to quantization with all parameters is uint8, but i can't find supported parameter to configure for converter

I really need and will appreciate any help or suggestions I may receive. Thank you so much.